# Replace number in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a this string:

```
text = "bla bl4a 12 bla 23 bla"
```

I want to replace all the numbers that are not a part of a word with a token `<num>`.

I know I can replace all numbers of a string like this:

```
text = re.sub(r"(\d+)", "<num>", text)
```

Unfortunately this also replace `bl4a` with `bl<num>a`. This should be the output:

```
"bla bl4a <num> bla <num> bla"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match [word boundaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26) either side of the number

```
re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "<num>", text)
```

Comment: Alternative without regular expression could be `" ".join("<num>" if s.isdecimal() else s for s in text.split())`